# Resizing Images PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm using a url link to resize images, such as:

```
image.php?name=butterfly&size=1100x1100
```

for example:

```
<img src="image.php?name=butterfly&size=1100x1100">
```

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])){ //name
    $image['name']  = $_GET['name'];
} else {
    $image['name']  = null;
}
if(isset($_GET['size'])){ //dimensions
    $image['size']  = $_GET['size'];
    $size = explode('x', $image['size']);
    $image['width'] = $size[0];
    $image['height'] = $size[1];
} else {
    $image['size']  = null;
}
if(isset($_GET['text'])){ //text
    $image['text']  = $_GET['text'];
} else {
    $image['text']  = null;
}
// File and new size
$filename = 'images/'.$image["name"].'.jpeg';

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output
imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = $image['width'];
$height = $image['height'];

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresized($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

My code works only for one part, which is the width, the image is resized to it's width but not height. Also when I resize my window, the picture get smaller every time. Thank you for your time and sorry for any bad explanation.

Comment: If the image is resizing with your browser then this sounds like a CSS/Styling issue

Comment: I don't have any css in it, it's jsut a different php code and when I resize the window with image.php it doesn't worj properly

Comment: The result from the first `imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);` call is not used.

Comment: Just a security concern. Unless this is a private website you might want to add a maximum size, otherwise someone can do this. <img src="image.php?name=butterfly&size=999999999x9999999999"> and you will probably crash due to out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the question? I didn't get it.

One reason why the code changes only the width it may be because of this part of the code:

```
`if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}`
```

only one of the sizes will change. Also, another reasons why is changing only the width could be that you have as original image and quadratic resolution (e.g. 800x600 - ratio 1,34) and then you keep changing it to a wider one (e.g. 1280x720 - ratio 1,77).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you don't understand the question, why did you answer it?

Comment: Didn't understood fully what he meant and I just wanted to help him, if he provides a feedback of my answer I could reply.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code logic, at any given time either your height or your width will change.
I tried it at my local host, width & height of my image was 600 X 400 and I passed 100X100 as parameter, it resized the image to 100X66, so the height did changed.